# unlink Permission denied

Tags: php, file

I'm having problem on how can I delete a file that is being created.it always says permission denied,I already saw some solution here in stackoverflow but it did not help me.so I just want to post my problem,maybe there is something wrong in my code.

```
        $tempbin = "fileimg.log";

        $PATH = "C:\\wamp\\www\\myproject\\fileimg.log";

        chmod($PATH,0775);
        unlink($tempbin);//here error permissin denied.
```

**EDIT:**

The solution for my problem,is that I forgot to close the file after writing.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: What if you really don't have permissions?

Comment: Where is fileimg.log located ($tempbin)? It looks like you have no permissions in that particular folder.

Comment: thank you for the quick reply.I'm just working in my localhost.so how do I set permission ?it is located in myproject folder

Comment: how do i set permission to my folder "myproject" ?

Comment: In windows chmod does not do a thing. Its good to add it to your script nontheless, if you migrate to an online linux box. Anyway to set permissions in windows look [here](http://www.ntfs.com/ntfs-permissions-setting.htm)

Answer (score 0):

If you can delete the file manually, so try to start your apache server with your own credentials